# Java, получить текущую дату в формате 2020-12-23 тип Date

Tags: java

```
   String sDate1="2020-12-23";  
   Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate1);
```

Возвращает - **Wed Dec 23 15:02:32 IST 2020**, при необходимом - **2020-12-23**.
Спасибо.

---

Всем спасибо.
Вопрос закрыт.

Еще раз благодарю (просто менее 30 символов не принимает :) ).

Comment: Не понятно чего же Вы хотите на самом деле. Ваш пример является вывернутым шиворот-навыворот вопросом.

Comment: Необходимо получить текущую дату, в переменную типа Date (передается в Query). Требуемый формат - 2020-12-23.

Comment: Ваш пример выглядит правильным. Так и надо поступать

Comment: К сожалению, переменная выходит в формате: Wed Dec 23 15:02:32 IST 2020. На что собстветнно, и ругается Java, мол нужно 2020-12-23, а ты даешь Wed Dec 23 15:02:32 IST 2020.

Answer (score 2):

java.util.Date -- это довольно сложно устроенный объект, который содержит внутри себя данные о дате и методы работы с ними. Вы, видимо, выполнили какой-то такой код:

```
String sDate1="2020-12-23";  
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate1);
System.out.println(date1);
```

Увидели в консоли `Wed Dec 23 15:02:32 IST 2020` и подумали, что в `date1` храниться какая-то неправильная строка.

Но в `date1` не хранится строка. Там хранится дата (т.е. довольно сложно устроенный объект и т.д.).

Вы очень ловко превратили *строку в дату* -- это хорошо. А теперь посмотрите, как вам превращать *дату в строку* нужного вида. Например, можно так:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String format = formatter.format(date1);
System.out.println(format);
```

Используя всё тот же `SimpleDateFormat`, кстати.

Просто когда она у вас строка -- она всегда одинаковая строка. А когда она у вас дата -- вы можете с помощью форматтера выбирать как именно должна выглядеть строка с датой.

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё задом наперёд в коде.

Метод `parse()` в SimpleDateFormat преобразует строку в дату. Естественно, если вы выведите в консоль полученный экземпляр Date, вывод будет `Wed Dec 23 15:02:32 IST 2020`, потому что выведется именно полученный Date.

А вам, наверное, надо обратное действие. Date превратить в строку. Для этого у SimpleDateFormat есть метод `format()`, в который подаётся экземпляр класса Date, а выходит красиво отформатированная строка.

Ещё раз:

- `parse()` - принимает строку, возвращает Date.
- `format()` - принимает Date, возвращает строку.