# Сохранить LocalDate в нужном формате

Tags: java, localdate

Нужный мне формат "dd/MM/yyyy". Но если я сохраняю дату в LocalDate, то он сохраняется "yyyy-MM-dd". Можно ли сохранить LocalDate именно в том формате?

```
LocalDate = date;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
date = LocalDate.parse(new Date(), formatter);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java, получить текущую дату в формате 2020-12-23 тип Date](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222786/java-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-2020-12-23-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы зашли не с того конца.

LocalDate - это объект, внутри которого хранятся данные о дате. Они всегда выводятся в одном формате *(посмотрите метод LocalDate.toString())*. Вот это:

```
date = LocalDate.parse(new Date(), formatter);
```

по-хорошему должно выдавать ошибку. Этот метод принимает не Date, а CharSequnce *(String например)*. Этот метод предназначен для того, чтобы получить LocalDate из строки. Чтобы получить красивый вывод LocalDate *(строку из LocalDate)*, вам надо использовать метод `format()`: